# consensus on the moving average

Tags: consensus

I research on consensus and need a forced delay between submittability of new blocks.
In bitcoin you use stochastics + processor clock speed. This allows you to choose an expected forced delay, which you chose to be 10min.

Quote from White Paper:
"To compensate for increasing hardware speed and varying interest in running nodes over time, the proof-of-work difficulty is determined by a moving average targeting an average number of blocks per hour. If they're generated too fast, the difficulty increases."

I do not see a way to find consensus on the present value of the moving average without yet implementing another consensus mechanism. But it appears necessary to have a very accurate global consensus on the exact value of the average because this value determines the mining difficulty. ***So how do you do it?*** Please give all the details in a novice-comprehensible way.

Comment: Hi Kaisong, are you asking how the difficulty adjustment works, or requesting help with designing an alternative consensus mechanism? In the latter case, you may be looking for “Verifiable Delay Functions” and want to look at “Proof of Space and Time”.

Comment: Seeing your other question after it was moved here from Crypto SE, I assume this linked question explains what you were asking about. Let us know if that's not the case.